# What is the scope of socket.emit()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, chatbot

We're using [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) for a chat application. Who will receive a message that is sent through `socket.emit()`? Over [here](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/), it is given like, `socket.emit()` will send a message only to one client.

Our requirement is achieving one to one communication (between a user and server and not between two users). Currently, we are creating separate rooms for different users and sending messages using `io.in(room).emit()`. The messages will be sent to everyone in that room and as per our application, a room will have only one user.

Can we achieve the same using `socket.emit()` by creating a single room and manage to respond to the particular client?

**UPDATE:-**

For more clarification, here is a scenario.

Five different users opens the chat box and everyone asks a different question to the server. We create five different rooms (one for a user) and respond to the users using `io.in(room).emit()`.

So, actually what we are doing here is, *in the server side, we are identifying the users based on the room* in which he is present. Is there a better way here? Heard `socket.emit()` will only respond to one client and was wondering whether it would ease our problem.

Comment: `socket.emit()` sends a message only to that one socket.  It's not clear what else you're asking. `io.in(room).emit()` sends to all sockets in that room.  `io.emit()` sends to all sockets connected to the / (default) namespace.  Those are your main options for sending messages.  socket.io NEVER sends from one user to another.  All communication is between client and server.

Comment: Make sure you keep clientside socket.io and serverside socket.io firmly differentiated. Server sends to one client, or everyone, or everyone except one client (possibly limited to a room, possibly limited to a namespace). Clientside only sends to server, period.

Comment: Yeah @Amadan. We would like the server to send the message only to the client who have requested the server with something. Such that, when two users are chatting with the server, the server should make sure that, it does not provide user1 with the answer for the question asked by user2.

Comment: In the client side, we are creating socket using, socket = io(). So, according to @jfriend00's comment, does that mean using socket.emit() in the server side will only send the message to that particular client who have created the socket?

Comment: `socket.emit()` only sends to that particular socket.  If you're in the client, then that's sending to the server.  If you're in the server, then you're sending to that particular client (the one that is associated with that socket object).  The server has access to lots of different socket objects (one for every client that is connected to it).

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement, User sends data to the server only. You use emit event in client side and on event in a server with the same method.

**Client**

Client **emit** method

```
socket.emit('DataClientToServer',{data : 'hello'});
```

Client **on** method, get data from server

```
socket.on('DataServerToClient',function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
```

**Server**

Server **on** method to get that data and send data to that client only using **socket.id**

```
socket.on('DataClientToServer', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            //Send data to that client only using socket.id
            io.to(socket.id).emit('DataServerToClient',{data : 'Server to Client'});
        });
```

For Detect which user send data, you send extra data like user unique **username** or **userid** or **objectid** etc.

Not needed room every user.

Hope this help you.

Comment: There is no issue in sending a message from the client to server. The question in one line is, how to send a message (server to client) such that the message will be sent only to the client who sent the message to the server? I have updated the question. Hope it clears.